# CakePHP: Posting data from shell to controller

Tags: php, cakephp, curl

I need to `POST` a param from shell to controller in CakePHP.

The problem is I should do it **without editing the Controller**.

Here is my Shell *(app/Console/Command/TestShell.php)*

```
<?php
App::uses('Folder', 'Utility');
App::uses('File', 'Utility');
class TestShell extends AppShell{
  public function main(){

    app::import("controller","Batches");
    $batches_Controller_obj = new BatchesController();

    $First_batch = 323;
    $batches_Controller_obj->createbatchfile($First_batch);
```

Here is the corresponding controller *(app/Controller/BatchesController.php)*

```
<?php
    App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
    class BatchesController extends AppController {
      public function createbatchfile(){
        if($this->request->is("post")){
          $this->request->data['batch']['batchname']; // Get the value of $First_batch here

        }
      }
    }
```

Is it possible to do it with `cURL` or any other means?

Comment: `I need to POST a param from shell to controller in CakePHP.` - why? Why wouldn't your controller and shell both call the same model method?

Comment: The only file I could change is the shell file.

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot better justification than "The only file I could change is the shell file." to get help doing something you shouldn't be doing. Doesn't it seem odd to you to be in a cli process - send a http request - to reach code _in the same app_ ? That's a bit like passing something to passengers in the same car by reaching out the window.

Comment: I am just asking if it is possible.

Comment: What you're asking is "is it possible to create a post http request" and - of course it is. It doesn't really matter for that question where you are posting to. Anyway: good luck :).

Comment: @AD7six  I am not asking that. Can you suggest the best way to pass the value of `$First_batch` to that controller?